# Cannot extract id from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to extract the users id from database, and it doesn't appear. This is the Login page:

```
 <?php
    include ("dbconnect.php");      
    session_start();
    $username = $_POST["username"]; 
    $password=$_POST["password"];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM autori WHERE autori.username='".$username."' AND autori.password='".$password."'
UNION
SELECT * FROM editori WHERE editori.username='".$username."' AND editori.password='".$password."'
UNION
SELECT * FROM recenzori WHERE recenzori.username='".$username."' AND recenzori.password='".$password."';");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) 
{
        $rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $_SESSION['user_id']    = $rand['id'];
        $_SESSION['username']   = $username;
        $_SESSION['password']   = $password;
        $_SESSION['user_type']  = $rand['id_usr'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type'] == 1) {
        echo "<script>alert('Sunteţi logat.');window.location.href='articole_pers.php';</script>";
    } else if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type'] == 3){
        echo "<script>alert('Sunteţi logat.');window.location.href='art_noi.php';</script>";
    } else if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type'] == 2){
        echo "<script>alert('Sunteţi logat.');window.location.href='articole_de_publicat.php';</script>";
    }
else { echo "<script>alert('Username or Email nu există !');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
}
}
?>
```

On the second page, where i'm trying to get the data, i use:

```
echo $_SESSION['username']; //it works
echo $_SESSION['user_id']; //it doesn't work
```

How can i extract the user ID from the database ?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions anymore. [As seen on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Do a `var_dump($rand)` somewhere. What's it got?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @Rudie ,this is what it's get with var_dump: Notice: Undefined variable: rand in C:\xampp\htdocs\About Technology\articole_pers.php on line 72 NULL

Comment: It is defined by this line: $rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

Comment: Since the message it saying it is _not_ defined, this means that the condition in your `if` was not true, and therefor the whole block did not get executed …

Answer (score 0):

Ok, First of all, try to use PDO objects or SQLi, mysql_query is deprecated for some years now.

make sure $rand['id'] gets a value by

```
print_r($rand)
```